# When the Facebook Token expired?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know facebook token right now will be expire because if `offline_access` have been removed.
But **how long this token will be expire? 60 days?**

How long for "normal" token will be expire? And I see in the token return , the expire is number "5143" ... This is second ? or minutes?

Comment: checked, thank you. Look like no more schedule app posting on facebook will work on future.

Comment: to check the detail of access token, use this following link https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

the long life `access_token` expires in **60 days**, the normal `access_token` expires in **2 hours** and **5143..** is seconds and you can also check `access_token` details using [Facebook Debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)

Answer (score 2):

There is a new option in App Advanced Settings: deprecate offline_access

If enabled the app will be issued long lived access token but you can't ask for offline_access. I believe after deprecation process is completed the expiry time will return to normals or they might leave it to 60 days.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the access token will expire in 60 days but you will still always need to handle two other cases (even with offline_access).

If the user either:

- Deauthorizes the application
- Changes their password

... then you will need to direct them to retrieve another client-side access token that you can exchange for your long-lived access token.

Do note however that even if a user logs out of your application, if you have asked for offline_access, your access_token will still be valid (assuming none of the other situations have also occurred).